# $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

I wan't to show that $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So I suppose toward a contradiction that it is finitely generated, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]=(x_1,...,x_d)$ where $x_1=p_1(1/3),...,x_d=p_d(1/3)$ i.e. they are polynomial expressions (with integral coefficients) in $1/3$, but then what element can't I express with linear combination of these elements, or where would there be a contradiction?

Comment: The proof works the same for $\Bbb Z[1/3]$.

Comment: Assuming they're all nonzero, an explicit element you can't express is $\frac{1}{3}x_1...x_d$. Of course to understand why, you probably need to see the answer on the other post

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @Max, if I take $x_1=1/3$ and $x_2=9$ than $\frac{1}{3}x_1 x_2=1$ which can be expressed, no?

Comment: Yes, of course I was thinking that the $x_i$'s weren't integers, but they can be. If they're not integers then the product works (and if some of them are, the product of the ones that aren't should work)